# Roslaunch and etc/pkg-name for yaml files

Tags: roslaunch, catkin, ros-hydro, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Hydro package includes both a launch file and a pair of yaml files.  The launch file gets installed by Catkin to ~/workspace/install/share/pkg-name/file.launch (CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION) and the parameter files to ~/workspace/install/etc/pkg-name/files.yaml (CATKIN_PACKAGE_ETC_DESTINATION).

The trouble is that roslaunch doesn't seem to know to look for the parameter files there ($(find pkg-name) resolves to ~/workspace/install/share/pkg-name).  I have two fixes, but both feel like hacks and workarounds:

1. Install the yaml files to CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION with the launch file.
2. Use < rosparam file="$(find pkg-name)/../../etc/pkg-name/file.yaml command="load" /> in the launch file

The first option has me wondering why there is a CATKIN_PACKAGE_ETC_DESTINATION if it isn't for param files.  The second is ugly and potentially brittle.

How can I make roslaunch find my parameter files more cleanly?  What is the ROS/catkin standard method/location for installing parameter files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125476/roslaunch-and-etc/pkg-name-for-yaml-files/) by [Nathan Powel](https://answers.ros.org/users/11561/nathan-powel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any resource file should have the same relative path from the package.xml file-  either in the source package as well as in the install space.

E.g. keep the files in `somewhere/myfile` in your source repo and install them to `$(CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/somewhere/myfile`.

That way your launch file can reference it with `$(find pkg-name/somewhere/myfile` which will work in devel space as well as after installation.

You should definitely not use relative paths with `..` and "escape" the package folder since that would not work without installing the package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nathan Powel](https://answers.ros.org/users/11561/nathan-powel/) on 2014-02-02**:
I guess that does seem more organized if the relative path structure is preserved, which I had not done even for the launch file.  That still leaves me with wondering what *would* properly go in CATKIN_PACKAGE_ETC_DESTINATION.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-02-04**:
You can get a package's `etc` directory using catkin's Python API, so it's possible to load files from it at runtime: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/_modules/catkin/find_in_workspaces.html

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-02-04**:
I don't think there's a C++ API for it, though; the lack of availability of the etc path to roslaunch is definitely a problem. Dirk attempted to address it here, but the pull request was never merged: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/228